# Multiple chat-room creation via socket.io client

Tags: socket.io, chat

Okay, I have gotten socket.io up and running on Node. Everything is peachy. However I am stumbling on creating specific functionality that I don't think should be that hard but that I can't find anywhere, looking through the APIs and socket.io-client.

Here is what I am looking to do. I have an application that acts as a chat between members of an organization. I know that socket.io has rooms so I could create a room for each two way conversation. I need to pass in an avatar, the text typed, the time.  That is it really. I am also going to write interactions to an SQL instance and I have that part figured out as well.  I want to do this from a web-browser. I have it connected, just need to figure out how to:

- Dynamically make rooms
- Pass and retrieve in custom data - avatars etc.

Here is my existing client code. I don't think I am very far away:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>  
    var socket = io.connect("http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8000");
 socket.on("connect", function () {  
    console.log("Connected!");
});
socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think maybe everywhere you said "slack.io" you meant "socket.io"? If so, please remove the "slack" and "slack-api" tags.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question and tags.

Comment: You're right. UGH!  Socket.io